# The fragment to how to use the Activity inside the httpclient

Tags: android, android-fragments, httpclient

I wrote the code for some httpclinet

Caused by clogged so easily because my server only allows two links action

Must be disconnected through replace HttpClient HttpClient link

Can be simply substituted in the same Activity

But the change is done the fragment to how to share the same HttpClient link

Requirements to implement replace function to complete disconnect

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

//Regardless of the implementation of several actions are repeated replace

private void JS() {
        HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("IP");

    List<NameValuePair> params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("s1","2"));

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.ISO_8859_1));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){
        try {
        String  strResult=EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        } catch (ParseException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

Need to complement other information on this, please inform me

Comment: Your question is not very clear, I'm not sure what your problem actually is.

Comment: sorry,I find the English ability of good friends to help me correction
Wait for me one hour